# Counting distinct values *that come before* the focal instance in different ways in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

An example/test data looks like the following. "dyad" is a group of 2 people who conversed with each other (1 row = 1 message) in a discussion "post". These observations are chronologically ordered.

```
 structure(list(post = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
    dyad = c("111_222", "111_222", "111_222", "222_345", "333_567", 
    "333_899", "333_990", "435_123", "435_555", "435_123", "435_111", 
    "435_555")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
), codepage = 65001L)
```

**What I'm trying to create are two variables: "response1"and "response2".**

- **response1**: The number of distinct dyad that is **(a)** different from the focal dyad (row) that **(b)** comes before the focal dyad **(c)** within a post.
- response2: This one is simply the order of the focal dyad within a post.

The outcome would look like:

```
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| post | dyad    | response1 | response2 |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1    | 111_222 | 0         | 1         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1    | 111_222 | 0         | 2         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1    | 111_222 | 0         | 3         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1    | 222_345 | 1         | 4         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 2    | 333_567 | 0         | 1         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 2    | 333_899 | 1         | 2         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 2    | 333_990 | 2         | 3         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 3    | 435_123 | 0         | 1         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 3    | 435_555 | 1         | 2         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 3    | 435_123 | 1         | 3         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 3    | 435_111 | 2         | 4         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 3    | 435_555 | 2         | 5         |
+------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much. It is now updated for your reference!

Comment: Why does `response1` equal 1 for the first row in `post == 2`?  Going by your definition, there are no dyads that come before that row within post 2.

Comment: @andrew_reece So sorry; I was in a rush. It is corrected now!

Comment: @akrun My bad; I think it is now accurately depicting the conditions for response1.

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df1 %>%
   mutate(response1 = cummax(match(dyad, unique(dyad))-1), 
      response2 = row_number(), .by = c("post"))
```

-output

```
  post    dyad response1 response2
1     1 111_222         0         1
2     1 111_222         0         2
3     1 111_222         0         3
4     1 222_345         1         4
5     2 333_567         0         1
6     2 333_899         1         2
7     2 333_990         2         3
8     3 435_123         0         1
9     3 435_555         1         2
10    3 435_123         1         3
11    3 435_111         2         4
12    3 435_555         2         5
```

Comment: could be dplyr version issue; for me when I run your code, .by is created as a separate variable/column!

Comment: @user14250906 you can use `df1 %>% group_by(post) %>% mutate(response1 = cummax(match(dyad, unique(dyad))-1), 
      response2 = row_number()) %>% ungroup` if you have an older version